# while loop is not working properly

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am writing code for my one of the exercises in freecodecamp.com called as [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) problem. For a while loop it  should stop executing the code inside it  when the condition becomes wrong.For  my case the while loop must stop executing the codes inside it when it finds that it seen a vowel in the charas array during iteration. I think my code is correct in my point of view, but while loop is not stopping execution when it sees a vowel instead it iterate through every element in the charas array.

Here is my code

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  var f="";
  var charas = str.split("");
  if(vowels.indexOf(charas[0])!==-1) {
      // vowel
    charas.push("w");
    charas.push("a");
    charas.push("y");
    f = charas.join("");
  } else {
    //if first letter  is a consonant or cluster of consonants
    var i = 0;
    while(vowels.indexOf(charas[i]) ===-1) {
     charas.push(charas[i]);
     charas.splice(i,1);
     i = i+1;
     }    
   charas.push('a');
   charas.push('y');
   f  = charas.join("");   
  }
  return f;
}

translatePigLatin("california");
```

Comment: What should be returned from this function ?

Comment: It takes the first consonant (or consonant cluster) of the input string, moves it to the end of the word and suffixes an "ay".If a word begins with a vowel you just add "way" to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you increment `i`. You move the first element from the start of the array and then increment `i` you are skipping a letter because what was `charas[1]` is now `charas[0]` and what is `charas[1]` was `charas[2]`.

If you step through the code and inspect the `charas` array you can see this happening:

Starting state:

> ["c", "a", "l", "i", "f", "o", "r", "n", "i", "a"]

`"c"` gets moved to the end
`i` is incremented to `1`

> ["a", "l", "i", "f", "o", "r", "n", "i", "a", "c"]

`"l"` is at position `1`, so it gets moved to the end.
`i` is incremented to `2`

> ["a", "i", "f", "o", "r", "n", "i", "a", "c", "l"]

`"f"` is at position `2`, so it gets moved to the end.
`i` is incremented to `3`

> ["a", "i", "o", "r", "n", "i", "a", "c", "l", "f"]

`"r"` is at position `3`, so it gets moved to the end.
`i` is incremented to `4`

> ["a", "i", "o", "n", "i", "a", "c", "l", "f", "r"]

`"i"` is at position `4`, the `while` condition is met, `"aioniaclfr"` will be returned.

If you just get rid of `i` and always check `charas[0]` it works like expected:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  var f = "";
  var charas = str.split("");
  if(vowels.indexOf(charas[0]) !== -1) {
    // vowel
    charas.push("w");
    charas.push("a");
    charas.push("y");
    f = charas.join("");
  } else {
    //if first letter  is a consonant or cluster of consonants
    while(vowels.indexOf(charas[0]) === -1) {
     charas.push(charas[0]);
     charas.splice(0,1);
    }
    charas.push('a');
    charas.push('y');
    f = charas.join("");
  }
  return f;
}

document.getElementById('out').textContent = translatePigLatin("california");
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

As a side note, this type of `while` condition will lead to an infinite loop if someone passes in a string that is all consonants, it will just keep shuffling the letters around because it will never find a vowel to stop it. To avoid this, I would add another `if` condition to check for that to make sure it won't happen:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  var f = "";
  var charas = str.split("");
  if (!str.match(/[aeiou]+/)) {
    // only consonants do something
     f = str + 'ay';
  } else if (vowels.indexOf(charas[0]) !== -1) {
    // vowel
    charas.push("w");
    charas.push("a");
    charas.push("y");
    f = charas.join("");
  } else {
    //if first letter  is a consonant or cluster of consonants
    while(vowels.indexOf(charas[0]) === -1) {
     charas.push(charas[0]);
     charas.splice(0,1);
    }
    charas.push('a');
    charas.push('y');
    f = charas.join("");
  }
  return f;
}

document.getElementById('out').textContent = translatePigLatin("wkrp");
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

`/[aeiou]+/` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) meaning any vowel one or more times anywhere in the string the `!` in `!str.match(/[aeiou]+/)` negates the result of `match`, so if there are no vowels in the string that branch of the `if` is followed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: [Up votes and/or accepting helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is always appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works as work cause

```
 charas.push(charas[i]);
 charas.splice(i,1);
 i = i+1;
```

After the first iteration it move 'a' letter at the begging as result i == 1 (in second iteration) charas[i] refers to consonant 'l'.

Comment: I suggest to remove letters from the begging after while cycle

Comment: yeah, it is the problem! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the condition to exit the while loop, use `i <= length of charas`. Check below snippet.

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  var f = "";
  var charas = str.split("");

  if (vowels.indexOf(charas[0]) !== -1) {
    // vowel
    charas.push("w", "a", "y");
    f = charas.join("");
  } else {
    //if first letter  is a consonant or cluster of consonants
    var i = 0;
    var len = charas.length;
    while (vowels.indexOf(charas[i]) === -1 && i <= len) {
      charas.push(charas[i]);
      charas.splice(i, 1);
      i++;
    }
    charas.push('a', 'y');
    f = charas.join("");
  }
  return f;
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are iterating AND modifying the same array at the same time

You can simplify your code like this

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  //start with vowel
  if (vowels.indexOf(str[0]) !== -1) {
    return str + "way";
  }

  var i = 0;
  var beforeVowel = "";
  var chars = str.split("");
  while (vowels.indexOf(chars[i]) === -1 && i < str.length) {
    beforeVowel += chars[i];
    i++;
  }
  return str.substring(i) + beforeVowel + "ay";
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("pig"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("eat"));
```

Comment: Yeah , that was the problem. Thanks for the code brother :)